# Cant resolve dependencies in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

Im trying to build a small Mean-Stack CRUD app. I am using the latest CLI and Angular 6

For that, i created a service file which imports a model, so far nothing spectacular..

but when it tries to compile now, it gives me:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/common/share.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/map' in 'C:\Users\Thorben\Desktop\FrameworksExam\Tut\client\src\app\common'
ERROR in ./src/app/common/share.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise' in 'C:\Users\Thorben\Desktop\FrameworksExam\Tut\client\src\app\common'
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
src/app/common/share.service.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Thorben/Desktop/FrameworksExam/Tut/client/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Ob
servable'.
```

my file looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Share } from './share.model';

@Injectable()
export class ShareService {
  selectedShare: Share;
  shares: Share[];
  readonly baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/shares';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  createShare(share: Share) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL, share);
  }

  getShareList() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL);
  }

  updateShare(share: Share) {
    return this.http.put(this.baseURL + `/${share._id}`, share);
  }

  deleteShare(_id: string) {
    return this.http.delete(this.baseURL + `/${_id}`);
  }

}
```

Am I injecting it wrong or what exactlz is the problem here :(

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 6.0, there is some difference import syntax. You can see [here](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library)